# Help w/ Retrieving XML via cURL

Tags: php, xml, parsing, curl

I've run into trouble with the following php code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?    minorRev=1&cid=55505&apiKey=58x5kuujub8xbb5tzv3a2a8q&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=    <HotelListRequest><destinationString>Seattle</destinationString>    <arrivalDate>08/01/2011</arrivalDate><departureDate>08/03/2011</departureDate><RoomGroup>    <Room><numberOfAdults>2</numberOfAdults></Room></RoomGroup>    <numberOfResults>1</numberOfResults></HotelListRequest>";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
$contents = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $contents;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The problem is that *$contents* contains markup that's not XML at all, so I can't parse it. It's confusing b/c entering the URL in my browser's address bar will display the XML document, but I can't seem to get a valid XML doc w/ this code.

Here is a snippet of the string that gets returned:

```
{"HotelListResponse":{"customerSessionId":"0ABAA83D-4428-4913-0382-28FBB1901EFC","numberOfRoomsRequested":1,"moreResultsAvailable":true,"cacheKey":"-32344284:1303828fbb1:-1ef9","cacheLocation":"10.186.168.61:7305","HotelList":{"@size":"1","HotelSummary":{"@order":"0"
```

Could someone explain to me where I'm going wrong?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove spaces: "/v3/list?    minorRev=1" -> "/v3/list?minorRev=1"

1. Make your URL correct, like

   `$url = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?type=xml&minorRev=1&cid=55505&apiKey=58x5kuujub8xbb5tzv3a2a8q&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%3CdestinationString%3ESeattle%3C/destinationString%3E%3CarrivalDate%3E08/01/2011%3C/arrivalDate%3E%3CdepartureDate%3E08/03/2011%3C/departureDate%3E%3CRoomGroup%3E%3CRoom%3E%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C/numberOfAdults%3E%3C/Room%3E%3C/RoomGroup%3E%20%3CnumberOfResults%3E1%3C/numberOfResults%3E%3C/HotelListRequest%3E';`
2. Add option to accept xml only -- in browser we have such header -- in curl -- no:

   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml'));`
3. PROFIT!!!

Comment: You are a genius! You solved a major problem of mine thank you so much!

Comment: @liveandream tnx, just press those "Up" button :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get XML, which may not be provided, you could always work with what you have, which appears to be JSON.

> $response = json_decode( $contents, true );

This will give you an associative array of your data, which can be much easier to work with.